# How do I turn a string into an array in Lua?

Tags: arrays, string, lua, lua-table

```
s = "this is a test string"
words = {}
for w in s:gmatch("%w+") do table.insert(words, w) end
```

Using this code I was able to separate each word but now I need to be able to access just the nth word. How could I print just the second word for example? could I convert it to an array somehow then use something similar to

```
print words[2]
```

Comment: You already have the answer: `print(words[2])`.

Comment: it does not work ("input:4: '=' expected near 'words'")

Comment: Edit in the complete code you use to try that.

Comment: I tried that code on it's own to see it it was working. That is the exact code

Comment: `print` is a function; you need parenthesis. Did you add those like in my example?

Comment: I had a mistype, it's working now, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
s = "this is a test string"
words = {}
for w in s:gmatch("%w+") do 
  table.insert(words, w) 
end

print (words [2]) --> is

for k, v in ipairs (words) do
  print (v)
end -- for
```

Apart from printing "is" it follows it by:

```
is
a
test
string
```

---

> ```
> print words[2]
> ```

You can only omit the parentheses for string literals and table constructors, like:

```
print "hello, world"
print ( table.getn  { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox" } )   --> 4
```

Comment: It's not true you can only omit parens for string literals, it also works for table constructors. See the [BNF in the specs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9): `args ::=  ‘(’ [explist] ‘)’ | tableconstructor | LiteralString`.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. **And** table constructors. I'll amend my post.